# What does geom ='errorbar' mean? Which algorithm is it?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a quick question on a hopefully a simple matter. In the following code, what does `geom ='errorbar'` mean? What algorithm is R using to calculate the error bars? I couldnt find it online and hope to find an answer here.

ggplot

```
stat_boxplot(aes(group = interaction(x, y)),geom ='errorbar', width = 0.6, size=0.75, color="black")
```

The overall code is as follows

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y,fill = factor(z))) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(z)),outlier.shape=NA, size=1, width = 0.6, fatten = 1, color="black") + 
  stat_boxplot(aes(group = interaction(x, y)),geom ='errorbar', width = 0.6, size=0.75, color="black")
```

Additionally, is there a way to display min and max with similar code?

Thanks!

Comment: `?geom_errorbar`

Answer (score 2):

`geom_errorbar` simply takes some values named `ymin` and `ymax` and connects them. What is generating those values is `stat_boxplot` in your example.

`?stat_boxplot`:

> #### Description
>
> The boxplot compactly displays the distribution of a continuous
>   variable. It visualises five summary statistics (the median, two
>   hinges and two whiskers), and all "outlying" points individually.
>
> ...
>
> #### Summary statistics
>
> The lower and upper hinges correspond to the first and third quartiles
>   (the 25th and 75th percentiles). This differs slightly from the method
>   used by the boxplot function, and may be apparent with small samples.
>   See boxplot.stats for for more information on how hinge positions are
>   calculated for boxplot.
>
> The upper whisker extends from the hinge to the largest value no
>   further than 1.5 * IQR from the hinge (where IQR is the inter-quartile
>   range, or distance between the first and third quartiles). The lower
>   whisker extends from the hinge to the smallest value at most 1.5 * IQR
>   of the hinge. Data beyond the end of the whiskers are called
>   "outlying" points and are plotted individually.
>
> In a notched box plot, the notches extend 1.58 * IQR / sqrt(n). This
>   gives a roughly 95% confidence interval for comparing medians. See
>   McGill et al. (1978) for more details.
>
> ...
>
> #### Computed variables
>
> ...
>
> ymin lower whisker = smallest observation greater than or equal to
>   lower hinge - 1.5 * IQR
>
> ...
>
> ymax upper whisker = largest observation less than or equal to
>   upper hinge + 1.5 * IQR